# Updating multiple DIV - tags with a single jQuery script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a page that pulls order statuses from a backend system and then shows the status updates on the page. **I need to make the page dynamic to load, since now the page takes too long to update at once.**

I got my code working so that the HTML page loads up first and then a single status update is loaded on the page.

Components:

1. index.php -page - basic page w. jQuery code that requests orders_updatestatus.php.
2. orders_updatestatus.php -page. Pulls info from a backend system and displays info. Receives what order to update via GET.

HTML (index.php - this works)

```
<div id="updateref"></div>
```

**jQuery: (part of index.php - this works)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Update order status
$(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'orders_updatestatus.php?reference=100000025',
    success: function (data) {
      $('#updateref').html(data);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

**UPDATED CODE**

What I was thinking was that that I need to create a div for every single order so that they could then be updated individually.

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT reference FROM orders;");
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
  print '<div id="updateref'.$row['reference'].'"></div>';
}
```

So, with the code above I'll something like this:

```
<div id="updateref20000"></div>
<div id="updateref20001"></div>
<div id="updateref20002"></div>
<div id="updateref20003"></div>
<div id="updateref20004"></div>
etc..
```

Everything works great until this point. Now I need your help on building the corresponding jQuery code so that it would update every 'updaterefXX' -div that it sees.

**My question is:** How to update the following code so that it every updateref -div is updated on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Update order status
  $(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'orders_updatestatus.php?reference=100000025',
      success: function (data) {
        $('#updateref').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Update/clarification:**  What I need is for the script to pull the orders_updatestatus.php with a GET variable for every div. 
Example:

With `<div id="updateref1000">` the script requests `orders_updatestatus.php?reference=1000` and displays it in `<div id="updateref1000">` when ready

With `<div id="updateref1001">` the script requests `orders_updatestatus.php?reference=1001` and displays it in `<div id="updateref1001">` when ready

etc. Thank you!

Comment: _"My question is: How to update the following code so that it every updateref -div is updated on the page:"_ Is each `<div>` `.innerHTML` expected to be set to the same value `data` at `$.ajax()` `success` function?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. The <div> tags should all be updated with the same function, but one by one.

Comment: So first <div id="updateref20000"></div> gets updated, then <div id="updateref20001"></div>, then <div id="updateref20002"></div> etc. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "one by one"? Are you expecting the same `data` to be set at each `<div>` with `.html()` at `success` of `$.ajax()`? Or do you expect the `<div>` elements `.innerHTML` to be set with different values?

Comment: I'm a PHP coder and when it comes to javascript/jQuery I'm a bit of a simpleton, my apologies. What I need is for the script to pull the orders_updatestatus.php with a GET variable for every div. So for <div id="updateref1000"> it pulls orders_updatestatus.php?reference=1000 , for <div id="updateref1001"> it pulls orders_updatestatus.php?reference=1001 etc. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use attribute begins with selector and `.each()` to iterate all elements having `id` beginning with `"updateref"`, `.replace()` to replace portion of `id` that are not digits to set at query string, set `.innerHTML` the current element within `success` callback of `$.ajax()` call

```
 $("[id^=updateref]").each(function(index, element) {
   $.ajax({
     url: "orders_updatestatus.php?reference=" + element.id.replace(/\D/g, ""),
     success: function(data) {
       element.innerHTML = data;
     }
   });
 })
```